# In Access, if a table displays a cell, display something else

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a database in access. I have form with a combo box which has 37 items to choose from. When the user fills out the form, the data will go into a table just fine, but instead of displaying what the items are in the combo box, it will display the id number, not the choice from the Combo. This combo pulls its data from a table with two columns. One is the ID which access makes you put in, and two, the cleaning type, which are the choices in the combo. I was wondering if there was a way to create some sort of if/then statement in VBA or if there was a function to display the information from the column exactly as is, not the ID number associated with it. This is the code which is attached to the save data button:

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strName As String
 Dim varItem As Variant

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO CleaningLog(Name1, Date1, Shift, Cleaning, Comments) VALUES ('" & Me!Text12 & "', '" & Me!Text15 & "', '" & Me!Combo25 & "', '" & Me!Combo19 & "', '" & Me!Text30 & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

All of the data inserts fine, except for Cleaning, which is in Combo19. This is the only one pulling data from a table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are settings in the GUI for the combo box which you can set the column to save in the database and the column(s) to display.

[image]

Notice the "Column Count" and "Column Widths" properties.  Column count is the number of columns of data your combo box should contain.  In your case, there should be two - ID and name.

Next see the "Column Widths" property.  This sets the width of each column of data.  Notice that in my example, the first column has a width of 0".  That means when the user opens the combobox, it will be invisible, and will only be able to see the second column.  However Access automatically knows that the first column stores the value of the object and is what would be stored in your table.